# Copy lines from multiple files in subfolders into one file

Tags: sed

I'm very very very new to programming and trying to learn how to make tedious analysis tasks a little faster.  I have a master folder (Master) with 50 experiment folders and within each experiment folder are another set of folders holding text files.  I want to extract 2 lines from one of the text fiels (experiment title on line 7, slope on line 104) and copy them to a new single file.

So far, all I have learned is how to extract the lines and add to a new file.

sed -n '7p; 104 p' reco.txt >> results.txt

How can I extract these two lines from all files 'reco.txt' in the subfolder of the folder 'Master' and export into a single text file?

As much explanation as you can bear would be great to help me learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` in combination with `xargs` for this.  On its own, you can get a list of all relevant files:

```
find . -name reco.txt -print
```

This finds all files named `reco.txt` in the current directory (`.`) or any subdirectories and writes them to standard output.

Now, normally you can use the `-exec` argument to `find`, which will run a program for each file found, except that typically multiple results are combined into a single execution (appended to the command line).  Your particular invocation of `sed` only works on one file at a time.

So, instead of `-exec`, you can use `xargs` which is essentially the same thing but with more control.

```
find Master -name reco.txt -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 sed -n '7p; 104 p' > results.txt
```

This does the following:

- Searches in the directory `Master` or subdirectories for any file named `reco.txt`.
- Outputs each filename with null-terminator instead of newline (`-print0`) -- this allows the full path to contain characters that usually need escaping (such as spaces)
- Pipes the result into `xargs`, which does the following:

  - Accepts null-terminated strings (`-0`)
  - Only puts at most one file into each command (`-n1`)
  - Runs `sed -n '7p; 104 p'` on that file
- Entire output is redirected to `results.txt`, which will overwrite any existing contents in the file.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Very helpful!